# In Russian card game Durak, is it efficiently to keep the trump cards till the end of the game?

Tags: durak

Speaking statistically - is it better to directly kill all weak cards with the trump ones, or is it better to keep the royal cards up to the end?

(card game [Durak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durak))

Comment: Not sure about statistics, but my gut feeling is that if the deck is empty, the one with more and higher trump cards wins. So it feels to me that it does make sense to hoard them even if it causes you to become unable to beat your opponent's lead and take up more lower cards in your hand as the result. This is completely unscientific though, it's just how I feel it works.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh But at the same time habing 20 cards at once is not that great.

Comment: It depends. If by stroke of luck you draw all the trumps and your opponent does not, you will eventually win even with 15+ cards in your hand. But then you will also win _without_ them ;) What I'm saying is, that it is possible to navigate the endgame to victory even with a lot of cards, if you have enough trumps and can lead (repeatedly) with several cards of the same rank, with a trump that the opponent cannot beat.

Comment: Btw 20 cards is more than half of the deck, let's be realistic here.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh Yeah Im playing Durak usually with my friends and when you lose on start having beaten 5 cards, not beaten the last one you’ll get 11 cards, the same thing again, 11+6 = 17, so it goes pretty fast if you can’t beat the income. Ive once taken enough cards and couldn’t get out from the multiples of cards, because i didn’t want to give away the trump ace.